# "bundle exec rake db:create" command throw error message, operation not permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am new to ruby rails, I have done setup in my machine and I am stuck at last step, after doing successfully "bundle", when I hit "bundle exec rake db:create" in my terminal I see a long error template report where I can find only following,

## Error Report

### Questions

Please fill out answers to these questions, it'll help us figure out
why things are going wrong.

- **What did you do?**

  I ran the command `/Users/ravibhatia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin/bundle exec rake db:create`
- **What did you expect to happen?**

  I expected Bundler to...
- **What happened instead?**

  Instead, what happened was...
- **Have you tried any solutions posted on similar issues in our issue tracker, stack overflow, or google?**

  I tried...
- **Have you read our issues document, https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/doc/contributing/ISSUES.md?**

  ...

### Backtrace

```
Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - /Users/ravibhatia/Desktop/Dev Code/fountain/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/rake 

 Please suggest, thank you.
```

Comment: Would you type on your terminal 'which rake' and share it here?

Comment: also, can you paste in your config/database.yml ?